# Is it possible to add image to content of label wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I wonder if it is possible to add an image to the content of the label.
Now label is something like that:

```
<Label Content="some text" />
```

And my target is to add a small icon near to the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `Content` to a `Panel` that contains both a `TextBlock` and an `Image`:

```
<Label>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock>some text...</TextBlock>
        <Image Source="pic.png" Width="40" Height="40" />
    </StackPanel>
</Label>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great. I have one problem - image and text in a different line, how I can put them all on the same line?

Comment: Thanks! One last question. Is it possible to change the background of an image or I must to have more image with different color?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments field.